# Python source "encoding not declared"

Tags: python, character-encoding

This is the top of my source file:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-16 -*-
import re
import unittest
```

Despite including the declaration at the top of the file, I get an error when I run this: "Non-ASCII character '\xff' in file ScrapeEdgar/parsers/parser8kex101_tests.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details".

Here's the full output:

```
usau810195:ScrapeEdgar reedn$ python -m unittest ScrapeEdgar.parsers.parser8kex101_tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/__main__.py", line 12, in <module>
    main(module=None)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 149, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 158, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 128, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 91, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
  File "ScrapeEdgar/parsers/parser8kex101_tests.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xff' in file ScrapeEdgar/parsers/parser8kex101_tests.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

Comment: have you tried `# coding=utf-8`?

Answer (score 0):

Python source files don't support the UTF-16 encoding.

> Any encoding which allows processing the first two lines in the
>          way indicated above is allowed as source code encoding, this
>          includes ASCII compatible encodings as well as certain
>          multi-byte encodings such as Shift_JIS. It does not include
>          encodings which use two or more bytes for all characters like
>          e.g. UTF-16. The reason for this is to keep the encoding
>          detection algorithm in the tokenizer simple.

See [PEP 0263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

Hope this helps.